# Unable to access ASP.NET core web application through IIS - HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

This is not a duplicate question, similar issue which are reported earlier are not relevant to below environment.

My Dev environment
Windows 10, IIS 10, Visual Studio 2017, ASP.NET core MVC project template.

I am new to Visual Studio 2017 and ASP.NET core. First thing noticed there are changes in project structure and there is no web.config. I have created a blank project and after publishing (Publish method as File System) web.config appeared in the target location.
I created a application pool and virtual directory pointing to the target location, but when I tried to access the application, it is giving HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error. But in debug mode (IIS Express), it works fine.

Follwing things I have 
1. Created a blank ASP.NET Web application and published, accessed in IIS, it works fine.
2. Changed the .Net CLR version and Managed pipeline mode of application pool, as mentioned in some other links, but it did not work.
3. I think there is some problem in web.config, when I tried click on Authentication icon in virtual directory, it is giving error says, There was an error while performing this operation.
Please find the screen shot below

[image]

Comment: Can you share the contents of web.config file?

Comment: It is just because you are new here, that you could hardly believe you hit an exact duplicate. If you use Jexus Manager to trigger the same error message, you will see clearly which OOB module is missing, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/oob-500.html IIS Express ships more modules than IIS 10, and that's why it works.

Comment: @Lex Li, Thank you so much. After installing DotNetCore.2.0.5-WindowsHosting it worked. Thanks a lot..